# How to fix flex mat-form-field container?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="flex-equal-width">
    <div>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="formfieldspacing">
        <mat-label>Login</mat-label>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="login" />
        </mat-form-field>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS styles:

```
.flex-equal-width {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
}

.flex-equal-width div {
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-basis: 0;
 }
```

Problem is after click inside input field the styles are broken:

[image]

If to remove styles:

```
 .flex-equal-width div {
       flex-grow: 1;
       flex-basis: 0;
     }
```

It work fine. What is problem here?

Comment: Can you possibly create stackblitz example we can play with? You could fork an existing example from material docs site.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-nwuunh?file=app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.html

Comment: https://angular-mat-form-field-nwuunh.stackblitz.io

Comment: did you save last version? I have some problems running it.

Comment: Are you really using those angular versions in your example? V5? It just might be the problem. The cdk/material is version 5.rc-0 and might be buggy. When having problems, using latest libraries usually helps.